# Problems during buying & selling using Binance API Python

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

Trying to use Binance Python API for selling and buying crypto. The problem is when an order is placed and the price changes, the order just stays there for an indefinite time.

I want to know if there is some way to check for this, update the price accordingly, and try to buy/sell again, rather than being stuck on it.

Also, this login should be async. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Heres a few common endpoints you can use to check on orders. I would recommend taking [these docs](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/account.html) and sticking them in your back pocket

```
# Check order status
order = client.get_order(
    symbol='BNBBTC',
    orderId='orderId')

# Cancel an order
result = client.cancel_order(
    symbol='BNBBTC',
    orderId='orderId')

# Get all open orders
orders = client.get_open_orders(symbol='BNBBTC')

# Get all orders
orders = client.get_all_orders(symbol='BNBBTC')
```

Comment: Thanks will look into it! Can you also help me make a function using the logic I want?